# Randomly storing elements from an array into a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, iteration, splice

I'm trying to create a simple memory matching game and I'm having trouble assigning one number to each table cell from my cardValues array. My giveCellValue function is supposed to generate a random number then pick that number from the array and give it to one of the table cells but I'm a little over my head on this one and having trouble accomplishing this task.

```
var countCells;
var cardValues = [];
var checker = true;
var createTable = function (col, row) {
    $('table').empty();
    for (i = 1; i <= col; i++) {
        $('table').append($('<tr>'));
    }
    for (j = 1; j <= row; j++) {
        $('tr').append($('<td>'));
    }
    countCells = row * col;
};
createTable(3, 6);
for (i = 1; i <= countCells / 2; i++) {
    cardValues.push(i);
    if (i === countCells / 2 && checker) {
        checker = false;
        i = 0;
    }
}

var giveCellValue = function () {
    var random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * cardValues.length) - 1;
    for (i = 0; i <= cardValues.length; i++) {
        $('td').append(cardValues[random]);
        cardValues.splice(random, 1);
    }
};

giveCellValue();
console.log(cardValues);
```

Comment: Careful, `i` and `j` are global, trouble!

Comment: @elclanrs I thought if you only define them within the function they are local?

Comment: Yes but they're not defined, you're missing `var` keyword so they become implicit globals. I've seen unexpected bugs due to this issue since all the loops share the same variable.

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mCfhm/1/

Comment: just to mention your rows for loop is adding columns and columns for loop adding rows

Comment: @elclanrs Thank you, I solved this but this doesn't solve my first issue.

Comment: Also see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mCfhm/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny That did it.
I didn't know about the eq method, thanks for showing it to me!
Do you think you could post one of these links in an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: @user2449973 sure I'll do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var countCells;
var cardValues = [];
var checker = true;

var createTable = function (col, row) {
    $('table').empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < col; i++) {
        $('table').append($('<tr>'));
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < row; j++) {
        $('tr').append($('<td>'));
    }
    countCells = row * col;
};
createTable(3, 6);

for (i = 0; i < countCells; i++) {
    cardValues.push(i % 9 + 1);
}

var giveCellValue = function () {
    var len = cardValues.length, tds = $('td');
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * cardValues.length);
        tds.eq(i).append(cardValues.splice(random, 1));
    }
};

giveCellValue();
console.log(cardValues);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mCfhm/)

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the problems that have already been mentioned in the comments above...

If I understand it right, you want to assign each of the numbers in cardValues to a random table cell?

Seems like the problem is with this line:

```
var random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * cardValues.length) - 1;
```

What this does is generates a random number **once**. If you access the variable `random` at a later time, you're not calling the full line of code again, you're just getting the same value that was calculated the first time. E.g. if the above code runs, spits out '7' as its random number and stores that in `random`, then **every time** you go through the for loop, the value of `random` will **always** be '7' rather than being re-generated every time - make sense?

Try putting the randomiser **inside** the for loop - that way it will be run multiple times, generating a new random number every time:

```
var giveCellValue = function () {
    var random;
    for (i = 0; i <= cardValues.length; i++) {
        random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * cardValues.length) - 1;
        $('td').append(cardValues[random]);
        cardValues.splice(random, 1);
    }
};
```

Actually, I'd change line 4 above to `random = Math.floor(Math.random() * cardValues.length);` too which should have the same effect.

Comment: Thank you, but this, and many other issues were solved in the above answer.